# MediaBrowserServiceCompat startService() for sdk 26

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I'm tasked with updating an app for sdk 26.

There's a service called `PlayerService` that subclasses `MediaBrowserServiceCompat` and in the `MediaSessionCompat.Callback onPlay()` override it calls:

`startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayerService.class))`

Is there a quick and dirty way to make this work with Android O?

The app allows the user to play/pause/scrub media while the app is backgrounded.